# MVVM: Delete a CustomerViewModel, but how to get the Customer model inside it?

Tags: mvvm, repository, viewmodel

I have a list of CustomerViewModels in a ComboBox. The selected CustomerViewModel I want to delete and also the Customer wrapped inside it to remove it from the repository.

But how can I access the Customer model inside the CustomerViewModel?

Comment: well this could work:

_customerRepo.Delete(new Customer()
 { 
     CustomerID = SelectedCustomerViewModel.CustomerID,
     FirstName = SelectedCustomerViewModel.FirstName,     
});

but seems more than a hack...

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, make your collection of customerviewmodels an ObserableCollection of CustomerViewModels.
what this buys you is a CollectionChanged Event that you could listen on with a delegate for changes to the collection ie deletion, so from there you could manipulate you model accordingly

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(VS.85).aspx

perhaps something like

```
public class CustomersViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomersViewModel> Customers { get; private set; }

    public CustomersViewModel()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomersViewModel>(GetCustomers());
        Customers.CollectionChanged += 
            (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.Action ==  NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                    {
                        foreach (CustomerViewModel customerViewModel in args.NewItems)
                        {
                            DeleteCustomer(customerViewModel.Customer);
                        }
                    }
                };
    }

    private void DeleteCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        // Call into your repo and delete the customer.
    }

    private List<CustomersViewModel> GetCustomers()
    { 
        // Call into your model and return customers.
    }

    ... ICommands ect... 

}
```

Comment: already use ObservableCollection etc... All here is setup fine just did not see that my customer object in the CustomerViewModel class has a "_" char at the beginning of the instance name so I did not see it when I typed "SchoolclassViewModel." ;-)

I put this in the CustomerViewModel: 
public Schoolclass SelectedSchoolclass 
        {
            get { return _schoolclass;} 
        }

to get the customer...

thx again without that post I maybe wouldnt have seen my typo ;P

Answer (score 1):

You might have already access to the `Customer` inside `CustomerViewModel` (the VieModel needs to expose the properties of the `Customer` so the View can databind on them; I usually do it by exposing the `Customer` or a copy of it directly).

The point is that you *should not* delete the `Customer` yourself. That's what the `ViewModel` is for, to expose an `ICommand` that deletes the associated `Customer`. Depending on which MVVM framework you are using, look into [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx) or another equivalent.

Your `CustomerViewModel` would have a

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
```

and your View would bind a `CommandTarget` (probably a `Button`) to this command. When the command is executed a private method of `CustomerViewModel` will be run, and you can delete the `Customer` from there without exposing the deletion mechanism to other parts of the code. For example:

```
public CustomerViewModel()
{
    this.DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.ExecuteDeleteCommand);
}

private void ExecuteDeleteCommand()
{
    // remove the Customer from the ObservableCollection of customers
    // and also delete it from the database, or do anything else you want
}
```